# Can a class derive from more than one abstract class?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, abstract-class

Just wondering if a class can derive from more than one abstract class? My intuition says no.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. c# do not support multiple inheritance of classes.
But you can have class that implements multiple interfaces.